# Semi-colons in URL changes to %3b via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

This is my .htaccess file -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^template\.php$ - [L]
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule . /template.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It's designed to funnel everything through /template.php so it processes the rest of the URL & domains.

For whatever reason, when there's semi-colons provided in the URL (which is an important piece of the URL constructing the listing queries on my real estate websites) the semicolons change to %3b which is NOT what I want.

Oddly enough this is happening on one website only... all of my sites are on the same server.

http://dev.brixwork.com/listings/city-Vancouver+West/area-Arbutus;Cambie;Coal+Harbour/order_by-create_date/order_direction-DESC/page-1

THe above test URL is fine.

However take that same file here..

http://suzannec.brixwork.com/listings/city-Vancouver+West/area-Arbutus;Cambie;Coal+Harbour/order_by-create_date/order_direction-DESC/page-1

And you'll notice that the ; between the subarea names (Arbutus, Cambie & Coal Harbour) mysteriously changes to %3b, and the page title generated is wrong as well, because it's not getting the proper array passed for processing.

I'm fully aware that this may NOT be an .htaccess issue... but that's the best I could think up.

Comment: I removed the first two lines.. and frankly I don't even understand what that does. But it seemed to have fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first rule is doing this. When I click on your second link, since it doesn't end with a slash or a period, it redirects me to the same URI except with a slash. Try using the `NE` flag so that the semicolons don't get encoded:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L,NE]
```

Not sure why the `dev` site isn't doing the same thing, unless it's missing the redirect rule.